# Problem with displaying XML design in TabSpec of TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm designed a TabHost and its having 3 TabSpec's so i need to add GridView for every TabSpec for that i created XML design for showing GridView and added like shown in below:

Creating TabHost:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Positions.class);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("positions").setIndicator("Positions",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.buy))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BuyPwr.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("buypwr").setIndicator("Buy Power",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.buy))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Trades.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("trades").setIndicator("Trades",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.buy))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

code for first TabSpec "Positions"

```
    public class Positions extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.posgrid);
    }
}
```

XML design for "posgrid.xml"

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TableLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Current Position"
        android:layout_width="100dp"        
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView android:text="Buy"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Sell"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
  </TableRow>

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="120dp">      
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/score_table"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">          
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Al"
        android:layout_width="100dp"        
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:text="1000"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>     
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also i added activity in manifest file like:

```
<activity android:name=".Positions" android:label="Pos"></activity>
```

So i didn't get any errors but "posgrid" design is not showing in Postions TabSpec, plz any one help me.

Thanks,
nag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible reason can be Layout_height and layout_width is missing in some tags like upper TableRow and TextView in Lower TableRow .

Comment: Hi Shailendra, i tried as you said that means by adding layout width and height but even though i didn't get it.

Comment: Hmm i found my answer, i declared TabHost and FrameLayout wrongly so that's why it doesn't displayed.